# How to properly define an interface for a JSON file in Angular and populate dropdown box while creating dependency

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been working on a fun project of making a cascading dropdown box filter and it's been challenge.

I have been trying to go step by step so I hope I can be clear here. I got this JSON file with data that I need to populate dependent dropdown boxes.

```
{"data":
{"events":
{"type":"cart_update",
    "properties":
        [{"property":"product_id","type":"string"},
        {"property":"variant_id","type":"string"},
        {"property":"category_level_1","type":"string"},
        {"property":"category_level_2","type":"string"},
        {"property":"category_level_3","type":"string"},
        {"property":"product_list","type":"string"},
        {"property":"action","type":"string"}]},
{"type":"view_item",
    "properties":
        [{"property":"product_id","type":"string"},
        {"property":"variant_id","type":"string"},
        {"property":"category_level_1","type":"string"},
        {"property":"category_level_2","type":"string"},
        {"property":"category_level_3","type":"string"}]}]},"success":true}
```

For that, I created interfaces to navigate my JSON file properly. Hope I did it correctly:

```
export interface DataInterface {
  events: Array<EventInterface>;
  success: boolean;
}
export interface EventInterface {
  type: string;
  properties: Array<PropsInterface>;
}

export interface PropsInterface{
  property: string;
  type:string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
     
  getData() {
    return this.http.get('./assets/data.json')   
  }
  }
```

next thing I need to figure out is, how to populate dropdown boxes with the different properties event[type] and properties[property]. And how to create dependency between them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

considered the changes below

```
**export interface ResponseInterface {
  data: DataInterface;
}**
export interface DataInterface {
  events: EventInterface[];
  success: boolean;
}
export interface EventInterface {
  type: string;
  properties: PropsInterface[];
}

export interface PropsInterface{
  property: string;
  type:string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {
  // getting inner data coming from http request
  props: PropsInterface[] = this.getData().pipe(pluck("data", "events", "properties"));
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
     
  getData() {
    return this.http.get***<ResponseInterface>***('./assets/data.json')   
  }
  }
```